# How do I populate a field with data that is in an array for each instance of the data. Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, foreach

I am trying to populate a field with data, particularly the name of a product, but a different name for each product. I can get the code to produce all 4 names in each of the 4 different products. Which is obviously not the desired result. I can also get the first product name to populate the field 4 different times, which is also not the desired result. I want each product name to be populated in its own field. Here is the code that I am using to grab the data from a nested object that contains among many things, the product name.

```
var ports = deviceList.ports;
List portList = [];

(ports).forEach((e) {
  portList.add(e);
});
print(portList);
```

Now, if I change the code like this

```
portList.add(e.productName);
```

I will get the product name 4 times in the spot where it should only show once, each one containing its own product name.

I created a function to attempt to help with this, but my result was the same, except for when I did this.

```
getPortInfo() {
  var ports = deviceList.ports;
  var portList = [];

  (ports).forEach((e) {
    portList.add(e.productName);
  });
  return portList[0];
}
```

Now it will give me the first product name of the 4, but each of the 4 product has the same name, the first in the list. I understand why this is happening, I just don't know how to get my desired result.

Here is where I am implementing my code to produce the product name.

```
 children: [
   AutoSizeText(
     portList.toString(),
     style: FlutterFlowTheme
        .of(context)
        .bodyText1
        .override(
          fontFamily:
              'Heebo',
          fontSize:
               24,
          fontWeight:
              FontWeight
                  .w600,
        ),
   ),
  ],
```

I have multiple instances of the product because of this bit of code, which is working properly.

```
child: ListView.builder(
  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  itemCount: deviceList.ports.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('test');
        },
```

On my api, under ports there are 4, so the length check here is correct. Which is why above I am getting the 4 item repeated 4 times.

Again, to sum all of this up. I need the 4 different product names to be separated and each name placed with its own product listing. Figuring this out will help in the other instances that I need to do the same thing. The area that says port, etc.

[image: This shows all 4 product names where only 1 should be for each of the 4 products]

Answer (score 0):

edit your code to be like

```
 AutoSizeText(
     portList[index],
     style: FlutterFlowTheme
        .of(context)
        .bodyText1
        .override(
          fontFamily:
              'Heebo',
          fontSize:
               24,
          fontWeight:
              FontWeight
                  .w600,
        ),
   ),
```

what you were doing wrong is printing the entire list instead of getting the element based on the index of the list

Comment: I see, but within the square brackets, I cant write the word index as it says it is undefined. If I put just one number, say 0 for instance, it will give me the first product, but will replicate it 4 times and not looping through and giving me each item  in the index .